# How to put a text into the center of its TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I want to put a text exactly in the center of its containing box, and in preview that's OK, but in emulator it has a problem.

[image]

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:background="#000"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="E"
android:textAllCaps="true"
android:textColor="#FFF"
android:textSize="75dp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: Try adding `android:includeFontPadding=false`

Comment: Thanks man, it solved my problem. You can write it as answer so I can mark it accepted.

Comment: Cool! Just added an answer - thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:includeFontPadding=false` to your `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="#000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:includeFontPadding=false
    android:text="E"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="75dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:includeFontPadding

Fonts have an inherent padding in them and this is what seems to be causing the problem.

Potentially it's just a bug in the preview why it's not showing up there but is in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Change `layout_height` to `wrap_content`